# Change the style of the block depending on the data in the data?

Tags: javascript

I have such a layout.

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" data="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"> 
   <img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
</a>
</div>
```

The date can be this: data="Apple iPhone 5s Silver 32gb"

Also it is necessary if is in the text Siver to apply to an element other class.

How can this be done?

Comment: Your question is vague. How about adding your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<style>
    .silver{
        color: silver; 
    }
</style> 

<?php 

$product = array("name" => "Apple iPhone 5s Silver 32gb",
                 "href" => "...",
                 "image" => "link-to-image",
                 "class" => "silver"); 
?>

<div class="item <?php echo $product['class']; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>" data="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" id="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip"  title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"> 
       <img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
    </a>
</div>
```

---